# Ultimate Multi Flat Shipping extension, stop rounding price

Tags: shipping, third-party-module, flat

I have installed Ultimate Multi Flat Shipping extension to my magento application. I want to stop rounding price.As example when I enter 3.325,it saved as 3.33. I want to stop this and want to keep it as 3.325. How can I do this?

[image]